# Native Drag + Drop file upload in Firefox 3.6

Tags: firefox3.6

I've recently been told by a colleague that Firefox 3.6 supports native drag and drop file uploads + image resizing from the operating system without any extensions or plugins required.

Can anyone post a code snippet or provide a link which demonstrates this new functionality (as I couldn't find much on a Google search)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://hacks.mozilla.org/2009/12/file-drag-and-drop-in-firefox-3-6/

Edit: also https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/-moz-background-size if that's the image resizing you're after

Answer (score 2):

It's reasonably non-trivial (for HTML) hence no code snippet, but there's a pretty good HTML DnD tutorial [over here](http://www.alertdebugging.com/2009/08/16/on-html-5-drag-and-drop/).

NB: Updated with correct link. (My bad.)

Answer (score 1):

Vimeo has a nice example of drag n drop upload for firefox 3.6 here:

http://www.vimeo.com/6055152