# Drag-and-drop file upload in Google Chrome/Chromium and Safari?

Tags: javascript, ajax, html

Drag-and-drop file uploading can be done in Firefox 3.6.

[A Google search for *html5 drag-and-drop file uploading -gmail*](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=html5+drag-and-drop+file+uploading+-gmail) gives things like:

- [Native Drag + Drop file upload in Firefox 3.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2121018/native-drag-drop-file-upload-in-firefox-3-6)
- http://www.appelsiini.net/2009/10/html5-drag-and-drop-multiple-file-upload
- http://www.thecssninja.com/javascript/drag-and-drop-upload

All of these guides use `FileReader` (or the Firefox 3.6's deprecated `getAsBinary`, which no other browser supports, either).

However, Google recently released an update for Gmail that allowed drag-and-drop file uploading in Chromium as well as Firefox, and [Chromium does not have `FileReader`](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=37785). I'm using the latest Chromium nightly, and it can drag-drop upload files, while not supporting `FileReader`.

I've seen someone mention that drag-drop uploading can be possible by dragging onto an `<input type="file" />`, but that can only support one file at a time, while Gmail's uploader can handle multiple files being dragged onto it, so that's clearly not what they're doing.

So the question is, how do they do it? How do you support Chromium for HTML5 file uploading? In addition, can you support Safari?

Comment: P.S. Reading the source code is pretty difficult, since Gmail's source code is pretty well obfuscated as a result of all the optimization they do on it.

Comment: P.P.S. The `FileList` of an HTML `<input type="file" />` is read-only, so you can't just graft a drag-dropped file into one of those, either.

Comment: Is it possible to change the title of this post? I just posted a duplicate questions asking about "drag-and-drop" in "Chrome" but it didn't match this question because the title uses Chromium (which most people don't use).

Comment: Okay, I've changed the title.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

WARNING: **This is compatibility code for very old versions of Safari and Chrome.** Modern browsers all support the FileReader API; here's one tutorial: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications

This code is now only useful if for some reason you have a need to support Safari 5 and older, or Chrome 6 and older.

---

One possibility is to use [the method used in SwellJS](http://playground.justswell.org/drag-and-drop-file-upload.html):

Use `<input type="file" multiple="multiple" />` like so:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="uploadform">
  <input type="file" name="dragupload[]" multiple="multiple"
  onchange="if (this.value) document.getElementById('uploadform').submit();" />
</form>
```

The input element can be styled to have `opacity: 0` and positioned (absolutely) over an element that accepts uploads. The entire form can be placed inside an `iframe` for "pseudo-Ajax" like behavior. And the upload element can be a layer hidden until something is dragged over it.

Such an iframe would look like:

```
<script>
<!--
  var entered = 0;
-->
</script>
<body ondragenter="entered++;document.getElementById('uploadelement').style.display='block'" ondragleave="entered--;if (!entered) document.getElementById('uploadelement').style.display='none'">
  <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="uploadform">
    Things can be dragged and dropped here!
    <input type="file" id="uploadelement" name="dragupload[]" multiple="multiple" onchange="if (this.value) { document.getElementById('uploadform').submit(); }" style="display:none;position:absolute;top:0;left:0;right:0;bottom:0;opacity:0;" />
  </form>
</body>
```

This should only be done when Safari or Chrome is detected (since other browsers don't support drag-and-drop onto `<input type="file" />` elements), and can be used in combination with the HTML5 `drop` event for Firefox 3.6+.

I can't tell if this is the method Gmail uses, but it certainly works about as well.

Comment: The entry count increment/decrement trick on your show/hide code is really handy.

Comment: Thank you for this post. Is it possible for you to link from here to a full example? one which may include the server side code?

or just explain (on asp.net) how can i access the files that were submitted from this form ("uploadForm")

Answer (score 13):

You may be interested on something more technology- and browser-compliant.

Seems to me that [Plupload](http://www.plupload.com/example_all_runtimes.php) does it well, supporting the following features:

- Chunking
- **Drag/Drop**
- PNG Resize
- JPEG Resize
- Type filtering
- Stream upload
- Multipart upload
- File size restriction
- Upload progress

for most of the following technologies:

- Flash
- Gears
- **HTML 5**
- Silverlight
- BrowserPlus

And yes, [since 2010.05.27](http://www.plupload.com/example_all_runtimes.php), it supports drag/drop for HTML5 running on Chrome beta.

Comment: Oh? Did you try the "HTML 5 runtime" of this page? http://www.plupload.com/example_all_runtimes.php

Comment: The HTML5 runtime version works for me with 6.0.472.25 dev on OS X.  It also seems to work with the Firefox 4 betas.

Comment: HTML5 upload work for me on Chrome 8.552.210 Beta on WinXp as well (only a few months and they've got 2 versions). Anyway thanks for the post!

Comment: For me: under html5 runtime, FF 15.0.1 works; Chrome 21 does not.

Answer (score 10):

I've got something working in Chrome after much, much, much detective work. This *only* works on Chrome. On Safari, it freezes. On Firefox, it won't let me drop the file. IE opens the dropped file instead. Even in Chrome, the drag and drop only works once, for some reason, after which you have to refresh the page. (A possible reason for this is that something is wrong with the event handlers.)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.onload = function () {
                var div = document.getElementById('div');
                div.ondragenter = div.ondragover = function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'copy';
                    return false;
                }
                div.ondrop = function (e) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < e.dataTransfer.files.length; i++) { // e.dataTransfer is a DataTransfer object (https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DragDrop/DataTransfer), e.dataTransfer.files is a FileList object (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/FileList)
                        var file = e.dataTransfer.files[i]; // file is a File object (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/File)

                        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
                        xhr.open('post', 'handler.php', true);
                        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                            if (this.readyState != 4)
                                return;
                            document.body.innerHTML += '<pre>' + this.responseText + '</pre>';
                        }
                        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');
                        xhr.setRequestHeader('X-File-Name', file.fileName);
                        xhr.setRequestHeader('X-File-Size', file.fileSize);
                        xhr.send(file); // For some reason sending the actual File object in Chrome works?
                    }

                    e.preventDefault();
                    return false;
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="div" style="width: 100%; height: 200px; border: 1px solid blue">Drop here</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

handler.php:

```
    // This is not a true file upload. Instead, it sends the raw data directly.
    echo htmlentities(file_get_contents('php://input'));
```

Comment: Using document.body.innerHTML += destroys the dom events. Avoiding this will fix your problem.

Comment: works great, i was told by a gmail dev that you should use dropEffect='move' for FF3.6+, havent tested in FF yet so not sure if this is still required

Answer (score 2):

You wouldn't need to use an iframe to do pseudo ajax uploading. Chrome and Safari both support [XHR2 uploads](http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-XMLHttpRequest2-20090820/#the-upload-attribute) with progress events so you can do progress bars etc.

Comment: ...yes, that much is obvious. The problem here is that all the tutorials I've seen use `FileReader` or `getAsBinary()` (i.e. the functions Chrome doesn't support) to XHR2-upload a file. I doubt this is _required_, so what I'm basically doing here is asking how one would go about it if one wanted Chrome support.

Answer (score 2):

For our own application, we do drag and drop for FireFox only. We revert to the traditional iframe upload for others. In order to detect that drag and drop is supported, we run this code:

```
if (typeof(window.File) == 'object' && typeof(window.FileReader) == 'function' && typeof(window.FileList) == 'object') {
   // DnD is supported!
}
```

Hope this is helpful to some.

Comment: You do mention that you do drag and drop for FireFox only, but for others who may use this code, Safari 5 (Windows) will return false for  the `window.FileReader` check, even though it handles file drops perfectly well. Still looking for a reliable, browser capability detection for File Drag and Drop...

Answer (score 2):

You can use html5uploader library: http://code.google.com/p/html5uploader/

It works with Firefox, Safari and Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

The latest browser support file upload well.
You could use:

```
xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();     
xhr.open('POST', targetPHP, true);
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('upload',file);
xhr.send(formData);
```

You do not need to set boundary or any head，just like this it works fine.
I tested this code in 
client:firefox 6.02 and in chrome 13.
server:tomcat with "spring mvc"

Answer (score 0):

you can use FormData to store the File, then upload it. e.g

```
function setUp(){
  var dropContainer = document.getElementById("container");
  dropContainer.addEventListener("drop",dropHandler,false);
  dropContainer.addEventListener("dragenter", function(event){event.stopPropagation();event.preventDefault();}, false);
  dropContainer.addEventListener("dragover", function(event){event.stopPropagation();event.preventDefault();}, false);
  dropContainer.addEventListener("drop", dropHandler, false);
  getResult()
}
function dropHandler(event){
  var files = event.dataTransfer.files;
  var count = files.length;
  form = new FormData();
  for(var i= 0;i<count;i++){
    form.append("file"+i, files[i]);
  }
  sendData();
}
function sendData(){
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();  
  xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", uploadProgress, false);  
  xhr.addEventListener("load", uploadComplete, false);
  xhr.addEventListener("error", uploadFailed, false);  
  xhr.open("POST", "/upload");
  xhr.send(form);
  var progressBar = document.getElementById('progressBar');
  progressBar.style.display = 'block';
  progressBar.style.width = '0px';
}
```

the demo is here(http://flexinnerp.appspot.com/) 
just enjoy it :)

Answer (score 0):

Set multiple attribute like:

input type="file" name="file1" multiple="multiple" class="DropHere"

and use this CSS DropHere class:

```
.DropHere
{
    height: 100px;
    padding: 3px;
    border: 2px dashed #555;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: default;
    background-image:url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8, <svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' version='1.1' height='100px' width='220px'><text x='55' y='75' font-size='20'>or drop files here</text></svg>");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

The file field will now look like:

[image: The file will now look like]

If you use asp.net you might also like this article I wrote "Multiple file upload with progress bar and drag and drop": http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/818561/Multiple-file-upload-with-progress-bar-and-drag-an