# Rails - input type=”file” multiple

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm still on the hunt for an elegant multi-file upload for Rails.

I just learned about the "input type=”file” multiple"

Does Rails support this? Any examples? tips on how to implement for uploading multiple photos to a photoalbum model in Rails?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails - Paper_Clip - Support for Multi File Uploads](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4001376/rails-paper-clip-support-for-multi-file-uploads) (AKA: See my answer there)

Answer (score 3):

What you need is that more somenthing like this :

> <%= f.file_field :attachment,
>   :multiple => true %>

Answer (score 3):

Here's a complete, working code snippet for Rails 5:

```
<%= form_for(@user, html: {multipart: true}) do |f| %>
    <%= f.file_field :picture, accept: 'image/png,image/gif,image/jpeg,image/jpg', multiple: true %>
    <%= f.submit 'Upload Picture' %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is easy in rails.  If you're using `form_for`, do it like so:

```
form_for(@user, :html => {:multipart => true}) do |f|
```

If you're doing this with `form_tag`, it works like so:

```
form_tag new_user_path, :multipart => true
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: I should have been clearer. I'm interested in the file input tag "multiple" where you click BROWSE and can select multiple files at one time. not having to click and browser with multiple input buttons. Make sense?

Answer (score 0):

I have used http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/multiple-file-upload/, and it looks good to me on jQuery-1.7.1 .

Hope it helps.