# Best Jquery Upload Script (aja

Tags: jquery, ajax, upload

there are many Jquery-Ajax-Upload scripts available but what is currently (for you) the best (stable) script?

Thank in advance!
Peter

Comment: Most of them use the flash plugin. you are aware of that?

Comment: There is no jQuery Ajax upload plugin. It's possible these days, to upload with XHR, but only a few browsers support that. Plugins that use Flash, aren't Ajax. [Upload with XHR example here.](http://js1.hotblocks.nl/tests/ajax/file-drag-drop.html)

Comment: You can of course implement pure Html / JavaScript Upload for all browsers but his require some special server side code. there is an extension for php and its also possible with asp.net.

Comment: [See this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856917/jquery-upload-progress-and-ajax-file-upload/4943774#4943774)

Comment: @DanielB ... This is exactly want i want.

Comment: @Peter: Which server type and server language you are using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best is [uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com)

It's a jquery plugin.
Cheers

Comment: please correct the url to http://www.uploadify.com/. But its using flash plugin.

Comment: Actually it's http://www.uploadify.com/

Comment: Corrected the URL, edit pending approvation.