# Get Uploading Process RAILS/JS

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, upload

i want to check in Javascript whether the uploading process of my rails controller is complete. how can i do this?
my intention is to get the amount of files that has been transfered (i'm doing some byte-checking in the controller and i decide wheter to upload or to keep the file on the client side).

is that even possible? i would do the upload in js but unless you cannot check the files in js i have to upload them via rails.

please help,
kind regards

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this ([here's one w/Nginx and jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856917/jquery-upload-progress-and-ajax-file-upload)) some of which include drag-and-drop support, etc.

What you want to google is something like `rails jquery file upload with progress bar` and choose an implementation among the many that are out there.