# Using jQuery File Upload with Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I followed the Railscasts episode (http://railscasts.com/episodes/381-jquery-file-upload) to get file uploads working on my site. Everything works the way the tutorial intended, but i'd like to change up one thing and haven't been successful thus far.

I'd like to form to NOT submit until after they've clicked a submit button. Right now, and I believe with the following js, the form submits when a user finds a file.

```
#Snippet
data.submit()


#Whole JS File
jQuery ->
  $('#new_update').fileupload
    dataType: "script"
    add: (e, data) ->
      types = /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i
      file = data.files[0]
      if types.test(file.type) || types.test(file.name)
        data.context = $(tmpl("template-upload", file))
        $('#new_update').append(data.context)
        data.submit()
      else
        alert("#{file.name} is not a gif, jpeg, or png image file")
    progress: (e, data) ->
      if data.context
        progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10)
        data.context.find('.bar').css('width', progress + '%')
```

I'd prefer to remove this and use a button instead because I have a textarea that I want the user to fill out before submitting the form.

How can I pause image upload until after the user clicks a button???

**Update**

Full JS file

```
jQuery ->
  $('#new_update').fileupload
    dataType: "script"
    add: (e, data) ->
      types = /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i
      file = data.files[0]
      if types.test(file.type) || types.test(file.name)
        data.context = $(tmpl("template-upload", file))
        $('#new_update').append(data.context)
      else
        alert("#{file.name} is not a gif, jpeg, or png image file")

      $("#submt_button").on 'click', ->
        data.submit()

    progress: (e, data) ->
      if data.context
        progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10)
        data.context.find('.bar').css('width', progress + '%')
```

Answer (score 2):

As the original answer stated, you'd be able to achieve this by removing `data.submit()`, however, you'd need to then ensure the "submit" event triggered the JQuery file upload:

[jQuery file upload: Is it possible to trigger upload with a submit button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10042184/jquery-file-upload-is-it-possible-to-trigger-upload-with-a-submit-button)

```
#Whole JS File
jQuery ->
  $('#new_update').fileupload
    dataType: "script"
    add: (e, data) ->
      types = /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i
      file = data.files[0]
      if types.test(file.type) || types.test(file.name)
        data.context = $(tmpl("template-upload", file))
        $('#new_update').append(data.context)
      else
        alert("#{file.name} is not a gif, jpeg, or png image file")

      $("#submit_button").on 'click', (formEvent) ->
        formEvent.preventDefault()
        data.submit()

    progress: (e, data) ->
      if data.context
        progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10)
        data.context.find('.bar').css('width', progress + '%')
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That is submitting the form, but the file is no longer attached with the form submission.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot? It is probably to do with the indenting

Comment: I'll show you the JS file I have in an update on my original question.

Comment: @JustinLicata I had a similar problem.  But my issue was that the form was submitting instead of jquery upload plugin submitting.  Add `preventDefault()` so the form doesn't submit.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the js, I noticed there is a data.submit(), remove that and it should not submit the form