# JQuery File Upload: sending two request on data.submit()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to Upload videos in my app using **Paperclip** and **jquery-fileupload-rails**

I followed [ulpoad file with paper clip and jquery](https://5minutenpause.com/blog/2013/09/04/multiple-file-upload-with-jquery-rails-4-and-paperclip/) to upload video, but was uploading video just as I select the video and don't wait for pressing submit button, So I followed 
  [1](https://5minutenpause.com/blog/2013/09/04/multiple-file-upload-with-jquery-rails-4-and-paperclip/): [jQuery file upload: Is it possible to trigger upload with a submit button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10042184/jquery-file-upload-is-it-possible-to-trigger-upload-with-a-submit-button/16047861?noredirect=1#comment67623651_16047861) to select a single video and upload it on submit button, not on selecting file.

But There is issue on whether I put submit button in the form or outside form.

When I put the submit button in the form than it sends two requests to pressing submit button, one with Video and second one without Video.

And If I put button outside form that it sends one request on pressing submit button but after successful create/update it remains on the same page.

All I wanted is that on pressing Submit, sending just one request and redirect to index page on successful create/update.

In _form.slim

```
= simple_form_for [:admin,add] do |f|
   .wizard-content
     .row
       .col-sm-6
          = f.input :video, multiple: false, wrapper: :horizontal_file_input
          button#submit_button.btn.btn-primary
            | Save
```

In adds.coffee

```
 jQuery ->
      $('#add_video').attr('name','add[video]')
      $('#add_video').fileupload
         $('#submit_button').off('click').on 'click', ->
           data.submit()
```

In controller I have

```
def create
     if add.save
       redirect_to admin_adds_path
       flash[:success]= "Add Created"
     else
       render :new
     end
   end

   def update
     if add.update(add_params)
       redirect_to admin_adds_path
       flash[:success]= "Add Updated"
     else
       render :edit
     end
   end
```

there is also  a _add.slim

```
= image_tag(@add.uploaded_file(:small), class: 'thumb')
```

I also created create.js.erb and edit.js.erb as suggested tutorial I followed (though, I didn't understand its use )

```
- if @add.new_record?
  |  alert('Failed');
- else
  |  if ($('h1') !== undefined) { $('h1').append("
  =j render partial: 'adds/add', locals: { add: @add }
  | "); }
```

Whats wrong with this?

Comment: Hi Muhammad.  What happens if you comment out the jQuery submit code?

Comment: @IAMZERG it submitsfrom without showing progress bar

Comment: Does it still submit twice or just once?

Comment: just one
secod one will be with data.submi() which I removed

Answer (score 1):

Try the button inside the form and use event.preventDefault(), because it´s seems that the form is doing his default action, that is send data and reload the page and also calling the js.

```
$('#submit_button').off('click').on 'click', (event) ->
  event.preventDefault()
  data.submit()
```

Comment: It send request one time but remains on same page,
however at console it says Redirected to http://localhost:3000/admin/adds
Completed 200 OK in 3112ms (ActiveRecord: 91.4ms)

Comment: You should debug a little to know where is the problem, add some puts in those methods to check if they are running, for instance before the redirect `puts ("add________")+add.to_json`. Also flash message should be before the redirect.

Comment: I have tried a debugger in create/update method, also uses PUT
every inch of code is running but still remains on same page

Comment: try to change the redirect.        redirect_to :root , to know if the code is reaching that line. Make sure you have it set on the routes.rb.

Comment: yes it executed, says,
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Completed 200 OK in 315ms (ActiveRecord: 69.9ms)

Answer (score 1):

When you put button outside form you can handle the `done` event and the redirect.
Remember this POST is ajax and if you POST a change or new element you have a response via ajax no via web browser page.

Some like

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    dataType: 'json',
    add: function (e, data) {            
        $("#up_btn").off('click').on('click', function () {
            data.submit();
        });
        done: function (e, data) {
           window.location.href = "data.next_url"; 
        }
    },
});
```

Maybe you need to response some json (instead of redirection `redirect_to admin_adds_path`) to pass from controller to javascript information (some like `success`,`error`,`next_url`,`others`)

Comment: I tried to place button outside from and than used $('#submit_button').off('click').on 'click', (event) ->
          data.submit()
        done: (e, data) ->
          alert("Upload finished.")
          window.location.href = "data.next_url";

But it seems that its not coming in done: method and stuck on same page

Comment: the alert never trigger?

Comment: no, record saved page stuck on same page , no alert

Comment: you know how debug with the browser console?

Comment: can you check the url of the ajax is OK and also the response?

Comment: I can put break points and see what are the values etc.
but at which point I can see response?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126541/discussion-between-inye-and-muhammad-faisal-iqbal).

Comment: Although I couldn't solve my problem but a learned a lot with your precious help.
Thanks bro

Comment: no problem. Can you update your code to know your latest code. I think you have problem with the request and response.