# Image uploading with ajax and c#

Tags: c#, ajax, file-upload

I'm trying to find a way to upload an image to a webserver without submitting a form and have decided to do this with ajax, but I'm struggeling to find some good examples of how to do this.

I would appreciate if someone had some examples, or could explain how this can be done. (I'm not using any ASP.net servercontrols).

Comment: I'm using webforms.. Forgot to write that :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery Upload Progress and AJAX file upload](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856917/jquery-upload-progress-and-ajax-file-upload)

Answer (score 0):

Look into this: http://www.plupload.com/
I am using it on my site

Answer (score 0):

An ajax post doesn't submit `<input type="file" ...`, so you'll need to do it another way.  If your browser supports the JavaScript (HTML5) File API, you're golden.  Otherwise things like jQuery uplodify are great.  http://www.uploadify.com/  It uses flash behind the scenes, so won't work great on the iPad, but the iPad browser has the File API.