# PHP and Ajax file upload - Can't get the tmp_name with $_FILES

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, file-upload

I'm trying to upload a file using Ajax, but I'm having troubles handling the file...
For test purposes I've build a simple code that looks like this:

JS:

```
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("POST",document.getElementById('upload').action,true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
var cmdStr="q="+str;
xmlhttp.send(cmdStr);

document.getElementById("ResponseDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
```

PHP:

```
$q=$_POST["q"];
echo $q;
```

It works fine and `xmlhttp.responseText` prints `[object File]`.

My problem, however, is that I need to get the temporary file name with `$_FILES["q"]['tmp_name']`. To do so I have changed the code to the following:

JS:

```
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("POST",document.getElementById('upload').action,true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("enctype","multipart/form-data");
var cmdStr="q="+str;
xmlhttp.send(cmdStr);

document.getElementById("ResponseDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
```

PHP:

```
$q=$_FILES["q"]["tmp_name"];
echo $q;
```

Problem is that now with `xmlhttp.responseText` I don't get anything.
Anyone knows what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: do a var_dump on $_POST["q"] and see what your result it. The answer may be there. <?php var_dump($_POST["q"]); ?>

Comment: @Robert checking with var_dump it `returns string(13) "[object File]"` when using $_POST (i.e. when it returned `[object File]`), while it returns `NULL` when using $_FILES (i.e. when it returned nothing). So it means I'm stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this answer for making file uploads with AJAX. It is possible, but not compatible in all browsers.

[jQuery Upload Progress and AJAX file upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856917/jquery-upload-progress-and-ajax-file-upload/4943774#4943774)

--

Alternatively, if you want on the fly uploads, there is a cool library you can get called 'Uploadify'. It's a flash/jquery (or HTML5 now) rig that allows you to upload files on the fly. In the flash version, last time I used it... you can add in callback functions to make it do essentially anything you want.

Some clever javascript could make this work for you.

http://www.uploadify.com/

Comment: Perfect thank's! I've looked at the other question and realized how to use `formData`. It has solved the problem, now it gets the file with Ajax as I was trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

AJAX doesn't do file uploads. It's not designed for that. The standard workaround is to have the JS code build a hidden iframe and do a standard POST-type upload in that. As such, if you try doing `echo $_FILES['q']['error']`, you'd probably have gotten `4` for "no file".

Comment: I've tried with `$_FILES['q']['error']` but still without any response from the server... My problem is that I would like to implement drag and drop to upload a file, isn't it possible anyhow? I actually don't really need Ajax, but for what I've seen around the only option seemed to be Ajax, but then if you say so I'm a bit confused...

Comment: This answer may have been valid at the time of posting but may not be completely correct today