# How to send a string along with file via ajax request to a php file?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I got a php file that saves file to server to a folder called upload it receives file via an ajax request every thing works fine so far the next requirement is to send a string along with the file to specify an upload folder & sub folder like "Course/Math" how to achieve that?

**JS**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$('#Upload').click(function(){
    var formData = new FormData($('form')[0]);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'uploadFile.php',  
        type: 'POST',
        xhr: function() {  
            var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
            if(myXhr.upload){ 
                myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress',progressHandling, false);
            }
            return myXhr;
        },
        success: completeHandler,
        data: formData,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    });
});

var progressHandling = function(e){
    if(e.lengthComputable){
        var percent = Math.round((e.loaded / e.total) * 100);
        $('#uploadprogress').css('width', percent+'%');
    }
}

var completeHandler = function(data){
    $('#message').text(data);
    $('#uploadprogress').css('width', '0%');
    $('#file').val('');
};
});
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {

} else {
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
  echo true;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Sample Example of Sending form data in ajax call with **[.serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)**

```
var formData = $('#myform').serialize;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'uploadFile.php',  
        type: 'POST',
        xhr: function() {  
            var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
            if(myXhr.upload){ 
                myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress',progressHandling, false);
            }
            return myXhr;
        },
        success: completeHandler,
        data: formData,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    });
```

If you want to add a string simply use like following:

```
var value = 'test';
var formData = $('#myform').serialize+"&newstring="+value;
```

### Update

File upload is <strike>not</strike> possible through ajax.
You can upload file, without refreshing page by using [IFrame](http://www.ajaxf1.com/tutorial/ajax-file-upload-tutorial.html) or [AjaxFileUpload](http://www.phpletter.com/Our-Projects/AjaxFileUpload/) Plugin.

Further Details here is [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4912777/2236219).

Also file some detail explanation here also:

- [jQuery Ajax File Upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320069/jquery-ajax-file-upload)
- [jQuery Upload Progress and AJAX file upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856917/jquery-upload-progress-and-ajax-file-upload)

Comment: How do i receive that in php? $_FILES[] won't work here right?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the HTML5 Upload element.

```
$("#FileUpload").change(function (e) {
 var uploadFile = e.target.files;
 if (uploadFile.length > 0) {
      if (window.FormData !== undefined) {
           var data = new FormData();
           for (var x = 0; x < uploadFile.length; x++) {
                data.append("file" + x, uploadFile[x]);
           }
           data.append("ELEMENTCLASSNAME", $("#ELEMENTID").val());
           $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'URL',
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                data: data,
                success: function (result) {
                     alert(result);
                },
                failure: function (result) {
                     alert(result);
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, p3, p4) {
                     var err = "Error " + " " + status + " " + p3 + " " + p4;
                     if (xhr.responseText && xhr.responseText[0] == "{")
                          err = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).Message;
                     console.log(err);
                }
           });
      } else {
           alert("This browser doesn't support HTML5 file uploads!");
      }
 }});
```

On the server side use the Request Object get the value:

```
              var versionName = Request["ELEMENTCLASSNAME"];
```