# how to get progress with % for uploading file using jquery or ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am uploading files I want to get progress length using jquery  we are getting default progress in bottom in chrome browser or other browsers   so I want get that progress  using jquery or ajax and display that  when uploading files.

here's my code

```
<form>
 <textarea name="comment" id="comment" cols="45" rows="2" style="width: 83%;margin-left: 12px;"></textarea>
  </br>
  <input type="file" name="fileField" id="fileField" value="Browse" style="margin-left: -224px;">
</form>
```

I AM UPLOADING VIDEO ONLY

Regards

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856917/jquery-upload-progress-and-ajax-file-upload

Answer (score 2):

I think this link will help you out

> [Ajax Image Upload with Progressbar Code](http://www.sanwebe.com/2012/05/ajax-image-upload-with-progressbar-with-jquery-and-php)
>
> [**Demo Here**](http://www.sanwebe.com/assets/ajax-image-upload-progressbar/)

Comment: it's not working i am uploading videos so i want progress for that

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this using jQuery form plugin. You can also see this link bellow. I guess this will be helpful for you.

[File upload progress bar with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15410265/file-upload-progress-bar-with-jquery)

a working demo is here  [Working Demo](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/progress.html)