# Read the contents of a "file" object?

Tags: javascript, file, drag-and-drop

So I have a "File" object (retrieved by handling file drag and drop from desktop). I can send the files to the server with ajax, and then throw them back for javascript to handle them. But is it possible to read the contents of it without doing all this?

[Here, play around with this fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/jcoc611/MN66W/7/) Drag any file to the box and use the variable `file`.

I've already tried all of the methods of this object...no luck. Can you get the contents of the file you just dragged into the browser?

PS: I would send the files to the server like this:

```
var ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
ajaxRequest.open("returnRawPostData.php");
ajaxRequest.send(file);
```

I might have missed something in the code above, but that's just because one doesn't use plain JS to do AJAX calls anymore.

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2657653/drag-and-drop-file-upload-in-google-chrome-chromium

Comment: I don't think that answered my question

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Using the links from *Martin Mally* (thanks a lot!), I came up with this:

```
var file = e.dataTransfer.files[0],
    read = new FileReader();

read.readAsBinaryString(file);

read.onloadend = function(){
    console.log(read.result);
}
```

Where `read.result` holds the contents of the file.

Comment: Be careful, this is an async method.

Answer (score 11):

I think it's possible; check these two articles:

1. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_files_from_web_applications
2. http://hacks.mozilla.org/2011/01/how-to-develop-a-html5-image-uploader/

They both manipulates with "dropped" file via JS/HTML before uploading to server. (e.g. picture resizing etc.) I hope it helps.

Answer (score 4):

[Most modern browsers](https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_blob_text) can now use the `Blob.text()` API, which provides a promise-based method of reading files.

Every item within a FileList (`inputElement.files`) is an instance of a Blob, meaning we can call `.text()` on any item within the FileList to read it as text.

This is asynchronous, and much simpler than setting up a FileReader and using events, if you're familiar with async code and promises.

```
async function readTextFromFileInput(input: HTMLInputElement): Promise<string | void> {
  if (input.files?.length !== 1) {
    // No file selected...
    return;
  }

  return await input.files[0].text();
}
```

Comment: .text() returns a promise, better call like this: `input.files[0].text().then((text) => { console.log(text); }).catch((error) => console.log(error));`

Comment: @PatrickKoorevaar Yes, it returns a promise, hence why it's got `await` in front of it, and is used inside an `async` function in the example, as well as saying it's "promise-based"...

Ignoring errors by logging them to console and doing nothing else isn't a great thing to do. I'd rather pass it up and let the caller of a helper function handle the error instead.

Comment: Ah sorry, you are right, I overlooked it. I added the logging in my code as example.

Answer (score 1):

I just use

```js
let reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsText(your_file_object);

reader.onload = function() {
    console.log(reader.result);  // prints file contents
};
```