# Validating or reading a remote image type in javascript

Tags: javascript, image, file

Here is a link to what I mean by magic numbers:
[file magic](http://www.astro.keele.ac.uk/oldusers/rno/Computing/File_magic.html)

How can I remotely read the first couple bytes (the magic numbers) of a file with JavaScript to determine whether or not it is an image file?

Comment: Yeah, I'm reading that it isn't possible.

Comment: [Read the contents of a “file” object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5201317/read-the-contents-of-a-file-object) could help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JavaScript is a client-side language in the main, so you can't simply programmatically read files hosted on other sites from your own page. `XMLHttpRequest` will let you retrieve remote data, but that's going to retrieve the whole file, not the first few bytes. Doing anything more fancy is going to require a server-side helper, e.g. a PHP script or similar.

You should also be aware that some HTTP servers will not allow you to retrieve a range of bytes from the output anyway - they'll always return the whole file. So, even with a PHP script using, say, curl or wget, you may not be able to get this to work for all remote sites:

[Is it possible to read only first N bytes from the HTTP server using Linux command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5787213/is-it-possible-to-read-only-first-n-bytes-from-the-http-server-using-linux-comma)

(The above covers command-line curl, but the conclusions are broadly applicable.)

**Edit**: Sergiu points out that adding the `Range` header to an `XMLHttpRequest` will work, at least for some servers (the Range header is optional for HTTP 1.1). However, cross-domain image retrieval will still need further support such as CORS.

Comment: Well, you can indeed load images from any domain - even without ajax. But you're right, you can only load the full resource as a whole.

Comment: Thanks. I understand this from some other readings now, and they designed JS in such a way to rid it of security holes. But it would have been useful.

Comment: You're referencing the `Same Origin Policy` which is not applicable in this case. However you're correct about the `everything or nothing` part.

Comment: @SaniHuttunen I believe all requests are subject to this, even images. See test fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/R6STS/1/

Answer (score 1):

There are other similar questions on SO. Like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9093152/retrieving-binary-data-in-javascript-ajax) one.
It might help you to read an image as binary data.

You will need to read the whole image and not just the first few bytes. This is a limitation of JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

You could use XMLHttpRequest for this:

- use the [Range](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.35.2) request header to specify that you only want a few bytes
- if the browser supports [Cross Origin](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/) requests, then you could even request images found on other sites, otherwise you'll have to work with your server only
- if the browser is new enough, you could even access the response as an [ArrayBuffer](http://www.khronos.org/registry/typedarray/specs/latest/) to access individual bytes as bytes, not as characters

This works for me:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', '/download/logo.png');
request.setRequestHeader('Range', 'bytes=0-5');
request.responseType = 'arraybuffer'
request.addEventListener('load', function() {
  console.log(new Uint8Array(request.response));
});
request.send();
```

Comment: Ok, now this is cool. Although not usable for me as I am writing a commercial application and I need to support old browsers as well as cross domain urls. I will definitely end up using this in some other projects though, thanks!