# HTML5 drag and drop file field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, file-upload

I want to enhance a critical form with drag and drop functionality. I know that modern browser are capable of this via HTML5 file API.

However I do NOT want an instant upload or to upload multiple files, I am simply looking for duplicate functionality to ye olde fashioned file field.

After doing a-little research I've found the HTML5 file API requires an independent upload from the rest of the form (lame). Which is not the desired behavior.

So I then considered making a standard file field and setting it to `position : absolute; visibility : hidden;` and having to follow around the mouse inside the the dropZone via `.mousemove`. But this is not possible as the browser window is out of focus while the user grab's their file!

I also attempted to make the file field huge and invisible, but styling the field in this way is not possible.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what ended up working, I set the vanilla upload field to `opacity : 0` and positioned it under the mouse when the mouse is over the visible dropZone `div`, via the `'dragover'` event.

`'dragover'` overcomes the problem with the browser window being out of focus, and provides `.pageX` and `.pageY` which I then bound to the invisible file field's `.top` and `.left`.

However the resulting position of the file field is different on osx vs windows OSs, so a catch had to be put in to position the file field appropriately based on OS. I am pasting my working code below, and I have written a lib that detects browsers, OS and devices. So you will need to find your own way to detect osx vs windows.

```
dropText  = $ '#dropText'
jdropZone = $ '#resume'
fileField = $ '#draggy'

unless $.browser.msie

    `var addEvent=(function(){if(document.addEventListener){return function(el,type,fn){if(el&&el.nodeName||el===window){el.addEventListener(type,fn,false)}else if(el&&el.length){for(var i=0;i<el.length;i++){addEvent(el[i],type,fn)}}}}else{return function(el,type,fn){if(el&&el.nodeName||el===window){el.attachEvent('on'+type,function(){return fn.call(el,window.event)})}else if(el&&el.length){for(var i=0;i<el.length;i++){addEvent(el[i],type,fn)}}}}})();(function(){var pre=document.createElement('pre');pre.id="view-source";addEvent(window,'click',function(event){if(event.target.hash=='#view-source'){if(!document.getElementById('view-source')){var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){if(this.readyState==4&&this.status==200){pre.innerHTML=this.responseText.replace(/[<>]/g,function(m){return{'<':'&lt;','>':'&gt;'}[m]});prettyPrint()}};document.body.appendChild(pre);xhr.open("GET",window.location,true);xhr.send()}document.body.className='view-source';var sourceTimer=setInterval(function(){if(window.location.hash!='#view-source'){clearInterval(sourceTimer);document.body.className=''}},200)}})})();`

    x = 0
    y = -50

    x = -200 unless device.mac
    x = -130 if device.mac      

    #alert x

    dragover = (e) ->
        #e.preventDefault()
        fileField.css top : e.pageY+y, left : e.pageX+x

    dropZone = document.getElementById 'resume'

    addEvent dropZone, 'dragover', dragover

    fileField.on 'change', ->
        fieldVal = fileField.attr 'value'
        fieldVal = fieldVal.split 'fakepath'
        fieldVal = fieldVal[fieldVal.length-1]
        fieldVal = fieldVal.substr 1, fieldVal.length if $.browser.webkit
        dropText.text 'Your Resume: '+fieldVal

else

    fileField.css
        position : 'static'
        opacity  : 1
    dropText.text 'Upload Your Resume Here: '
```