# Show filepath via iFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have a webpage where I need to get a filepath of a local file on the user's computer. I was thinking to have an iFrame where a user drags in the file, and the response is the filepath.

For example:

[ in ] user drags file into iFrame of webpage
[ out ] webpage show the filepath of the file dropped (/Volumes/path/file)

How, exactly would I do this? (a link to a code example or tutorial would be great)

Here is the best answer I could find on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7890676/651174.

Comment: for obvious security reasons can't access file path

Comment: How do file browse buttons work then? Also, I don't need access to the file, I just need the name of the path.

Comment: browser is able to do things you have no access to with javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting the file path is a security issue. The closest you can get is the [fakepath](http://jsfiddle.net/EaPDV/). You can also use `files[0]` instead of value to get more information on the file.

Consider using HTML5 file drag-and-drop with the HTML5 FileReader API. [This tutorial](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/javascript/drag-files-into-the-browser-from-the-desktop-HTML5.html#fbid=AujL2WR0GgP) explains how to do it.

Comment: If you need to get only the name, then just do something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/2x99G/).