# jquery on drop get full path name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, file, drag-and-drop

i have a simple webapp, with this piece of code :

```
$(document).on('drop', '#dropfile', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).css('border', '6px #6BFF38 solid'); //vert
    var file = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files[0];
    alert(file.name);

    return false;
});
```

The "alert(file.name)" return just the name of the file. I know it's a usual question, but i didn't find the answer. How can i get the full path of the file instead of only the name ? Is there any parameter of the file to get it ?

Answer (score 2):

Answer by : Alexander Zinchenko

Link : [Get URL of resource that is drag-and-dropped on field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7820704/get-url-of-resource-that-is-drag-and-dropped-on-field)

In Firefox you can use file.mozFullPath. However, this variable presents only in Firefox and don't work in Chrome or Safari.

**Addendum :**

**Due to security reasons, a files path information is never exposed. Even mozFullPath does not return the full path of file.**

From mozilla website description for **mozFullPath** : This **feature is non-standard** and is not on a standards track. Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between implementations and the behavior may change in the future

Comment: Yes i already seen it but, is there a variant for Chrome and others ?

Comment: No, due to security reasons, a file's path information is never exposed.

Comment: Ok i think i have to find another way... Thanks by the way