# How to get url of an image via drag and drop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop

I want to use php to copy an image to my server which is easy. But is there a way to get the url that I would be copying from using Jquery drag and drop so that the user can simply drop an image in a box and then submit a form.

Thanks
Ian

Comment: Can you clarify "the url that I would be copying from" ? Are you talking about the user uploading a file from their computer, or the user dropping an image that's already on the internet?

Comment: Sorry, I meant dragging it from an image that is already on the internet. Such as Google images

Comment: here is a post discussing about drag and drop http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2657653/drag-and-drop-file-upload-in-google-chrome-chromium-and-safari

Comment: I am not trying to create a drag and drop upload, I just want to be able to get the url (http://somesite.com/image.jpg). And then put that in a text field

Comment: try this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11214053/drag-and-drop-images-from-another-website-to-mine

Comment: Correct, I ended up using something exactly like that!

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
var data = $(event.dataTransfer.getData('text/html'));
var src = event.dataTransfer.getData("Text");


var img = data.attr('src'); // if link then it is showing undefined
if (!img) {      // if link then we are getting it from linked img source
  var img = data.find("img").attr('src');
```