# Drag and Drop images from another website to mine

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop, cross-domain

I ran a quick google and SO search and found similar questions but none were well formed and most were old and looked abandoned (no answers, and no comments for a while). So here goes...

I want to be able to collect the url (only the url) of an image being dropped onto my site from another website.. (i.e. I have two chrome windows open. Window A has my application in it. Window B has imgur in it. I open an image click and drag it to my window and let go. Now I need to know the url of the image dropped on my page).

Here is the code I was working with for local files.

```
$(document).on('drop', function(e) {
    var data = e.dataTransfer || e.originalEvent.dataTransfer;
    console.log(data); // data.files is empty
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});​
```

Again I do not want to upload anything.. i'm not trying to do anything fancy... I just need to know the location of the image being dropped on the page from another website.

Comment: I think the problem is: if the site is not using the HTML5 drag and drop API, when a user drags the image, the browser gives him pure data, and no type of meta information (as the src, which is what you are expecting).

Comment: What do you mean by "Running the HTML5 drag and drop API". As for the rest of your comment I honestly think you have the entire thing confused.

Comment: I'm talking about this: https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DragDrop/Drag_and_Drop
(Ok, I was wrong. You indeed get the URL when you drag a image. I'll search something before the answer).

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/19564982/746754.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/2Jet2/70/

```
$(document).on('dragover', function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
});
$(document).on('drop', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.items[0].getAsString(function(url){
        alert(url);
    });
});​
```

I get `"http://static3.flattr.net/thing/image/9/4/5/5/0/huge.png?1326712342"` When I dragged that image from another browser window.

`.getAsString` takes a callback which gets the url as argument once it's called

Doesn't work on firefox

Answer (score 6):

You can use this

```
$(document).bind('drop', function (e) {        
    var url = $(e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData('text/html')).filter('img').attr('src');
    if (url) {
        jQuery('<img/>', {
            src: url,
            alt: "resim"
        }).appendTo('#yourId');            
    }
    return false;
})
```

Comment: e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData may be won't work your browser cause operating system does not affect.

Answer (score 2):

Based on Yunus's answer , this seems to work in FF:

```
e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData('text/html').match(/src\s*=\s*"(.+?)"/)[1]
```

Comment: Tested in chrome but doesn't work. everything is fine until: e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData('text/html'), which value is displayed on the console but it can not be used as String.

Comment: for me work on chrome v30.0 and firefox v24.0, thank you;-) where did you find this trick? :-)

Comment: Good to know that it works now on Chrome. @m1uan: I worked it from Yunus suggestion.