# Correct content-type for sending this AJAX Post data

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, spark-java, spark-framework

I am having problem sending base64 image data using ajax post
I think I have the wrong value for Content-Type but have tried *application/json*, *text/json* and *image/jpeg* without any success

Javascript

```
  function sendFormData(fD)
    {
        var urls = fD.get('urls');
        console.log('urls', urls);

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('POST', '/editsongs.update_artwork');
        alert(urls);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "image/jpeg");
        xhr.send(urls);
    }
```

Browser console shows

```
["data:image/jpeg;base64,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…
```

Java Server code

```
public String updateArtwork(Request request, Response response)
    {
        System.out.println("Received artwork");

        for(String s:request.queryParams())
        {
            System.out.println("---"+s);
        }
        System.out.println("ReadParms");
        return "";
    }
```

just outputs

```
Received artwork
ReadParms
```

**Updated to Send as Form Instead**

```
// Once we got everything, time to retrieve our objects
function sendData()
{
    var fD = new FormData();

    // send Files data directly
    var files = imgList.filter(
        function isFile(obj)
        {
            return obj.type === 'file';
        }
    );

    files.forEach(
        function appendToFD(obj)
        {
            fD.append('files[]', obj.file);
        }
    );

    // for elems, we will need to grab the data from the server
    var elems = imgList.filter(
        function isElem(obj)
        {
            return obj.type === "element";
        }
    );

    var urls = elems.map(
        function grabURL(obj)
        {
            return obj.element.src;
        }
    );

    if (urls.length)
        fD.append('urls', JSON.stringify(urls));

    sendFormData(fD);
};

    function sendFormData(fD)
    {
        // but here we will just log the formData's content
        var files = fD.getAll('files[]');
        console.log('files: ', files);
        var urls = fD.get('urls');
        console.log('urls', urls);

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('POST', '/editsongs.update_artwork');
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xhr.send(fD);
    }
```

then on server I have

```
 public String updateArtwork(Request request, Response response)
    {
        System.out.println("Received artwork");

        for(String s:request.queryParams())
        {
            System.out.println("***"+s);
            System.out.println(request.queryParams(s));
        }
        System.out.println("ReadParms");
        return "";
    }
```

and its outputs

```
    Received artwork
    ***-----------------------------330219842643
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name
    "urls"

    ["data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wCEAAkGBxMSEhUSExIWFhUXFxgXGBcYFRgXFxkdGBcWGBgYFx0YHSggHR0lHRkYITEhJSkrLi4uFyA1ODMtNygtLisBCgoKDg0OFQ8PFSsZFRkrLSstLSstKysrLS03KystLSstKy03LSstLSstNzc3KysrLS0tKysrKysrKysrKysrK//AABEIAKoBKQMBIgACEQEDEQH...."]
    -----------------------------330219842643--

ReadParms
```

So I'm now getting the data but I don't understand really understand how to parse the Content-Disposition part in Java.

This code wasn't originally written by me, as you can see the *FormData* is constructed it doesnt come from an actual form. My first attempt was to try and extract from *FormData* and send in different way, an alternative would be to not store in *FormData* in the first place but dont know how to do this.

**Update 2**
Tried just sending first url rather than formdata or an arrya of urls, because actually there is only ever one url.But it just doesnt work, nothing received by server ?

```
function sendFormData(urls)
{
    console.log('urls', urls[0]);
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', '/editsongs.update_artwork');
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "text/json");
    alert(JSON.stringify(urls[0]));
    xhr.send(JSON.stringify(urls[0]));
}
```

Comment: no clue what fD.get does, but is that form data? Is it more than one image?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34779799/upload-base64-image-with-ajax

Comment: epascarello yes it was a FormData object but hasnt the data beeen extracted out of FormData with my code

Comment: Maybe this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34779799/upload-base64-image-with-ajax

Comment: Doesnt explain why it doesnt work, Its not a large image so I dont understand why it doesnt work

Comment: I'm not familiar with what you're doing on the server side, but it looks like you are trying to get the body of the request with `queryParams()`, which would get query params in the url. That also explains why it's truncated in your second example, urls can only be so long. Figure out how to read from the body (`getReader()`?) using your first method and get your Base64 string that way

Comment: @Clint i guess you've hit the point....Obviously the loop is not working and i guess the reason is what you've told

Comment: @Clint sorry the output is misleading its not truncated the I added dots so the SO question not so large. But I dont know how to parse Content-Disporttiion.

Comment: Ive tried again just passing simple json, but it just doesnt get anything at server end. I'll update question again because this would be my preferred way to do it

Comment: @PaulTaylor See my comment above on the `queryParams()`. You are trying to get the data the wrong way. Research how to read data from the body. Also disregard my comment on the truncation, the form data is stored in the body as well and as you said, you added the dots yourself. Just a shot in the dark here, but try `body()` instead of `queryParams()`

Comment: @Clint thankyou you are correct using body() does give me the data. But I am more confused than ever now since I have some regular post queries that send form data and in those cases using queryParams() does work ?

Comment: Yes Spark-framework -ok that sort of sounds right, although it doesnt totally answer since when I was sending Form-Data and Content type  "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" it wasnt returning the data nicely like it does with an actual Form Post but maybe that is irrelevant really since I didn't want to send as a Form anyway.

Comment: Just found this, https://www.firstfewlines.com/post/spark-java-ajax-post-example/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to view data in the body using `queryParams()`, which will give you the query params that are located in the url.

Load data from the request body using `body()`.