# How to drag and drop files into web browser?

Tags: browser

I want to select a few files and be able to drag and drop them into the web browser for my website. What is the most reliable way to drag and drop files/photos across major browsers like Firefox and Chrome also does Google provide any libraries for this?

Answer (score 1):

I hope you want the feature same like gmail attachment feature (We can just drag and drop files).

For this we need to use flash. I hope, in Gmail they are using flash[image: Gmail Attach a file]

Check with this posts, you will get some ideas (using native DnD)

1) [Drag-and-drop file upload in Google Chrome/Chromium and Safari?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2657653/drag-and-drop-file-upload-in-google-chrome-chromium-and-safari)

2) [Native Drag + Drop file upload in Firefox 3.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2121018/native-drag-drop-file-upload-in-firefox-3-6)